# html2pdf.js : adding html component as footer

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I am working on a project in which I am converting html content to pdf using html2pdf.js library.
I have my own react components for header and footer. Can I add these components to the pdf as header and footer that must be applied to each generated page.

I have tried adding text to footer using :

```
pdf.text(
       pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 115,  
       pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 14,
       "Footer text"  
      );
```

...this code.

But I don't want to add plain text.
I am expecting an html element along with custom CSS styling to be added as footer.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.